# GSM location to coordinates

Tags: android, gps

I have a device that sends me it's location. It usually sends the coordinates obtained from the GPS, but if there isn't good GPS signal, it makes a GSM triangulation and sends me the MCC, MNC, LAC and CELLID values.

Having these 4 values, I need to obtain the position coordinates (latitude, Longitude). To achieve this, I'm trying to use the google's GLM hidden service (http://www.google.com/glm/mmap). It is supposed that pasing these 4 values to that service, it returns the latitude/longitude coordinates, but there is not much information about this service on the net.

With the recolected information, I have coded a small app that does this operation, but is not working. This is what Locgact shows:

```
11-21 13:02:29.692: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11990): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
11-21 13:02:31.264: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11990): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
11-21 13:02:43.506: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.gsmlocation.MainActivity.transform(MainActivity.java:114)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at com.gsmlocation.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
11-21 13:02:43.516: W/System.err(11990):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
11-21 13:02:43.526: W/System.err(11990):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
11-21 13:02:43.526: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-21 13:02:43.526: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-21 13:02:43.526: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-21 13:02:43.526: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-21 13:02:43.536: W/System.err(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 13:02:43.536: W/System.err(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-21 13:02:43.536: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-21 13:02:43.536: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-21 13:02:43.536: W/System.err(11990):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my code:

```
public Location transform(int cellID, int lac, int mcc, int mnc) {

    try {
        URL providerAddress = new URL("http://www.google.com/glm/mmap");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) providerAddress.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        writePlainData(outputStream, cellID, lac, mcc, mnc);

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        dataInputStream.readShort();
        dataInputStream.readByte();

        int code = dataInputStream.readInt();
        if (code == 0) {
            double lat = dataInputStream.readInt() / 1000000D;
            double lon = dataInputStream.readInt() / 1000000D;

            coordinates.setLatitude(lat);
            coordinates.setLongitude(lon);

            return coordinates;
        } else {

            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



protected void writePlainData(OutputStream out, int cellID, int lac, int mcc, int mnc) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

    dos.writeShort(0x0E); // Fct code

    dos.writeInt(0); // requesting 8 byte session
    dos.writeInt(0);

    dos.writeShort(0); // country code string
    dos.writeShort(0); // client descriptor string
    dos.writeShort(0); // version tag string

    dos.writeByte(0x1B); // Fct code

    dos.writeInt(0); // MNC?
    dos.writeInt(0); // MCC?
    dos.writeInt(3); // Radio Access Type (3=GSM, 5=UMTS)

    dos.writeShort(0); // length of provider name

    // provider name string
    dos.writeInt(cellID); // CID
    dos.writeInt(lac); // LAC
    dos.writeInt(mnc); // MNC
    dos.writeInt(mcc); // MCC
    dos.writeInt(-1); // always -1
    dos.writeInt(0); // rx level

    dos.flush();
}
```

The line that the LocCat points is:

```
connection.connect();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u r geating `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` so run your code in `AsyncTask`

```
 class LoadingLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            public Location transform(int cellID, int lac, int mcc, int mnc) {

    try {
        URL providerAddress = new URL("http://www.google.com/glm/mmap");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) providerAddress.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        writePlainData(outputStream, cellID, lac, mcc, mnc);

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        dataInputStream.readShort();
        dataInputStream.readByte();

        int code = dataInputStream.readInt();
        if (code == 0) {
            double lat = dataInputStream.readInt() / 1000000D;
            double lon = dataInputStream.readInt() / 1000000D;

            coordinates.setLatitude(lat);
            coordinates.setLongitude(lon);

            return coordinates;
        } else {

            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But, how do I call then to the transform() method?

Comment: No, I mean... I could call the asynctask in onCreate, but how do I pass the params to the transform method?